# basemapのインストールが正常にされない

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

matplotlibでGPSのデータを地図上に表示するコードを作ろうと、basemapのインストールを行ったのですが、様々な方法を試しても

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named basemap
```

と表示されます。

これまで行った方法としては、

1. ```sh
   $ sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap
   ```
2. ```sh
   $ wget https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.0.7rel.tar.gz
   $ tar xvf v1.0.7rel.tar.gz
   $ cd basemap-1.0.7rel/geos-3.3.3
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ sudo make install
   $ cd ..
   $ python setup.py install
   ```
3. 2のwgetをgit cloneにして2の流れを行う。

いずれも最後まで行ったにもかかわらず、上記のエラーが発生します。
numpyとmatplotlibが入ってないのかとも考えましたが、最新バージョンをインストールされていました。使用しているOSはxubuntu 16.04です。
どうすればインストールができるのか対処法を教えてください。

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 16.04のPython3.5の仮想環境で、次のコマンドでインストールして動作しています。

```
sudo apt install proj-bin libproj-dev libgeos-dev
pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/v1.1.0.tar.gz
```

Google Colab でも試してみましたが動作します。
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_Xw_MEIriI0leP-v8vlmhUj6BLJLKmoV

過去のbasemapのインストーラーには問題があって手作業で追加の設定をしてやる必要があるようです。v.1.1.0で解消されているので、それ以降のものを使えば問題なくインストールできます。

basemapの後継がCartopyです。basemapは2020年でサポート切れになるのとCartopyの方が少し使いやすいので、これから始めるのであればCartopyを使った方がいいと思います。

Cartopyのインストールは、次のようにします。

```
sudo apt install proj-bin libproj-dev libgeos-dev
pip install cython numpy
pip install cartopy
```

Answer (score 0):

質問者様と全く同じような環境で問題になった方がいらっしゃいました。

[ImportError: Ubuntu 16.04.3 - Installing basemap module on python 2.7.12 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977599/importerror-ubuntu-16-04-3-installing-basemap-module-on-python-2-7-12)

私の環境は全く違いますが、この質問サイトでこたえてあるようにすれば、
成功するかもしれません。

解答の骨子としては、Anacondaを利用するということのようです。
Anacondaをインストールした後、アナコンダ・プロンプトを開き、

```
conda install -c anaconda basemap
```

と打ちます。

> and I can eventually import basemap from mpl_toolkits

とあるので、最終的には`mpl_toolkits`というモジュールから`basemap`をインポートできたと
語られていました。

追記です。
以下の記事に別の解答が載せられていました。

[Problem importing a module (mpl_toolkits.basemap) in Python - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555474/problem-importing-a-module-mpl-toolkits-basemap-in-python)

リンクも貼ってあったので、読んでいただければと思います。回答者の方が要約していた文章ですが、

> This article describes how to install basemap. And Here is the git repo, and here is a browser downloadable source code.

この記事（リンクあり）は`basemap`のインストールの仕方を記載しています。そしてここ（リンクあり）ダウンロード可能なソースコードのブラウザです。

> From the article, in short:
>    1) Download the source if apt-get install does not work out
>    2) install the source (super useful if installing to a virtual environment) by: 
>   cd basemap-1.x.x
>   python setup.py install

手短にその記事を言ってしまうと、
もしapt-get install コマンド？がうまくいかないのならば、そのソースをダウンロードせよ。
（仮想環境へインストールするなら、超便利？）そのソースをインストールせよ。

> Then here is also the doc, with instillation guides and how to test if you have installed correctly. (just run from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap in terminal)

それからここもそれのドキュメントです。インストールが正常にできたかどうかをテストする方法と、インストールガイドです。（ターミナルでBasemapをインポートし、mpl(mapplotlib?)　toolkits.basemapから走らせるだけです。

私も詳しくないので、正確かどうかはわかりませんが、リンクを辿っていただければ分かっていただけるかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。anacondaを使わなくてもインポートできるものかと考えておりましたがやはり使わないと難しいのでしょうか。ひとまず試してみます。